# OpeNni: Color coordinates to depth coordinates

Tags: java, kinect, openni, homogenous-transformation

I was wondering how can I convert a coordinate that i acquired from a 
full res color image to coordinates in the depth stream.

E.g, i got (763,234) from the full res color and i want to know what 
is the (x,y,z)  from the depth image ? 
(btw i'm doing this in java, but an answer in c++ is probably easily 
translatable)

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input device allows it, you can simply use "*GetAlternativeViewPointCap*", as shown in the following C++ code. In this case, the depth map is automatically transformed so to become aligned with the color image. Therefore, given a coordinate (x,y) of a pixel on the color image, it becomes sufficient to query the depth map at the same position.

```
m_context.InitFromXmlFile(path,m_scriptNode);                               
m_context.FindExistingNode(XN_NODE_TYPE_IMAGE, m_imageGenerator);                       
m_context.FindExistingNode(XN_NODE_TYPE_DEPTH, m_depthGenerator);                       
if (m_depthGenerator.IsCapabilitySupported(XN_CAPABILITY_ALTERNATIVE_VIEW_POINT)) {
    m_depthGenerator.GetAlternativeViewPointCap().SetViewPoint(m_imageGenerator);
}
```

If this approach is not viable, you should estimate the transformation between the two cameras. A book such as "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision" describes all the necessary background and algorithms.